# is_singular() for custom post type in pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-type

I'm trying to modify the query for a specific post type, whatever page (single or archive) is currently displayed. I'm using the `pre_get_posts` filter with this test:

```
if ( is_singular( 'evenement' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'evenement' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

but the `is_singular` conditional tag never seems to be true when I'm on a single `evenement` page.

Any idea what I could have missed?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried $wp_query->is_singular() instead ?

Comment: This happened two months ago... I found a solution in the mean time, but I don't ever remember what this was about.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and figured that you can't use `is_singular` in `pre_get_posts` because the queried object is not set at this point. It make sense: the query isn't processed yet, and `is_singular` return `true` if a post is being displayed - we don't know at this point if the query return any result, as of **pre**​_get_posts).

You can use instead the `post_type` query parameter like this:

```php
if($query->get('post_type') === 'evenement') {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use '$query->is_singular' in combination with a post_type check:

```
if ( $query->is_singular && $query->get('post_type') === 'your_post_type' ) {
    // your code
}
```

If you only test for post type then you will also modify the query for archive pages.